# How do I get videos on some streaming sites to play

Tags: 18.04, firefox, google-chrome

I cannot play any videos in movies123 or putlocker. I have got video on YouTube, Facebook, Netflix and many others.

When entering the video page when using Windows, the page loads and then in the bottom left of the video next to the play button, the time comes up 0.00/44.32, but when I use Ubuntu 18.04 the page loads but the time always stays 0.00/0.00. I load the restricted extras loaded some suggested codecs?

In Firefox, when I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> I get this:

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)
>
> The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

This is the site http://movies123.ac any movie or video on this site. I have this site save in my Chrome Browser. when I am logged into my google account on my windows 10 laptop, windows 8.1 PC or any of my Android devices it works.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! A linkn to a specific movie that is producing this behavior would be useful in determining the problem. Without that or at the very least the domain addresses in question, All we can do is guess which is unlikely to provide you with the desired solution.

Comment: The link you provided looks like it's sole purpose is gathering information. Personally I wouldn't consider it a "legit" site.

Comment: I'm not interested in these "spamware" sites personally, however you might find [this enlightening](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-flash/pull/39)

Comment: @Elder Geek thank for your time and help. sorry if i have wasted your time. My partner and I like to us some of these sharing site to watch media that is no always available in our country. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and more codecs:

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Close and re-open Firefox to so it can see the newly installed codecs and you should be able to view videos that previously wouldn't play.

If you are still unable to view the content (assuming it's even real content, many "streaming" sites are fake and don't actually host content) press <kbd>F12</kbd> and look at the Network tab in Firefox to see which files are loading. If any of them are video files you can try to download them manually and play them with VLC.

Comment: I have done this already, this is was how I got other web videos to play. 'sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg'
'sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras '

Answer (score 1):

### Which Movies123 and which Putlocker?

There are hundreds of fake websites with variations of the names. You should give an explicit web address rather than a generic brand name so people can confirm you are visiting a legit site.

Some "clones" may contain Window's viruses and someday maybe even a Linux virus too!

### Adblock Plus

For the internet in general, and free movie sites in particular, I think Adblock Plus gives best results. With over 500 million downloads (developer's claim) Internet users have it more than any other package.

It is available for both Google Chrome and Firefox. It is installed as an extension in both web browsers.

### Caveat Emptor (Buyer Beware)

Please read comments posted by others below for potential negative consequences.  Because it is free the price can't be any better. But as an old saying goes "There is no such thing as a free lunch". That said right now I'm using "free" Ubuntu, Linux, Xrandr, Firefox, gmail, gnome, systemd, plus my own `multi-timer` and `eyesome` I've written and given away.

Comment: Adblock Plus and Adblock have had shady history with selling the ability to include advertisements. Try uBlock Origin instead.

Comment: @KristopherIves chromium-ublock-origin and xul-ext-ublock-origin can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @karel Thanks! It appears the version of `xul-ext-ublock-origin` is `1.13` while my version in Firefox is `1.17` - the same for the Chromium versions in the repositories.

Comment: @KristopherIves I'm not sure what you mean. I've been using Ad Block and then Ad Block Plus for years and I know if I forget to install on a fresh installation I see tons of pop-up ads. After installation websites complain I'm using an Ad Blocker. Google by it's nature tracks web traffic and sells your demographics for ad placement on many many websites. It could be some websites I visit have ads sold by Ad Blocker instead of Google but I don't think so. Anyway If I do see a pop-up ad again, which Ad Blocker has been blocking, I'll remember your comment. Thanks.

Comment: This is the site ( http://movies123.ac) it is save in my Chrome Browser. when I am logged into my google account on my windows 10 laptop, windows 8.1 PC or any of my Android devices it works.

Answer (score 1):

The videos on those websites do not load automatically in Ubuntu. You have to click the play button to start loading them. Clicking the play button also opens advertising websites, which is probably the reason why the videos don't load automatically. These websites also engage in bandwidth shaping which varies based on the time of day. The bandwidth shaping also extends to throwing occasional network errors. If you have an ad blocking extension installed the videos will play anyway, except on Brave web browser which is more focused on security than the other web browsers and blocks both ads and trackers by default.

Comment: I hit play button and left it and think halo just keeps going around. thanks for your help. If I can't fix it I'll just have to keep using windows in the other partition. Thanks heaps for your time